# Using Regex to swap some letters and numbers around

Tags: regex, string, vb.net

I'm trying to use RegEx in vb.net to swap a pattern of letters and numbers around and am just having no luck in understanding how to use RegEx or if it is even possible with RegEx.

I have a string that looks like this "blah blah ABCXY20 blah blah" and I need to change it to "blah blah ABC20XY blah blah"

So there is other text before and after the part I need to work with that I just need to stay how it is. I'm just interested in moving the "XY" letters to after the number. It may not be the actual letters "ABC" or "XY" it could be a different pattern, but whatever it is, the pattern is always consistent or the same three letters then the same two letters then a number or arbitary length.

Comment: Please better describe what the range of possible inputs would be.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but the problem has already been solved. No need to down vote both the question and the answer.

Comment: I downvoted neither, and you should not be making such assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that'd be possible. My guess is that here we can likely have an expression similar to,

```
([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{2})([0-9]+)
```

and make a replacement with `$1$3$2`.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/QMNtDb/1/)

If we'd be having exact five letters, our choices for instance would be

```
(?=ABCXY)([A-Z]{3})([A-Z]{2})([0-9]+)
(?=ABCXY)(ABC)(XY)([0-9]+)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/kWiGs1/1/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply. That does indeed solve the problem. Is there a way that I could lock down what the three letters and two letters are if known in advance, to prevent any false positive just in case there was some other letters and numbers that just so happen to match the pattern. For example, if I knew the first three letters were always going to be "ABC" and the second two always going to be "XY". Thanks again.